# Set panel default button gives error, must be ibuttoncontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, panel

I am trying to set default button for asp panel. Instead of asp button I am using button control with type="submit". I am getting error: "The DefaultButton of 'pnlSSN' must be the ID of a control of type IButtonControl.”.

This is the code I have:

```
  <div class="input-append" id="divSSN">  <asp:Panel ID="pnlSSN"
 runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSSN">                     
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSSN" runat="server" CssClass="span8" Width="200px"
 placeholder="Enter valid Social Security Number">
 ValidationGroup="validationSSN" />
 <button runat="server" id="btnSSN"
 onserverclick="btnSSN_Click" causesvalidation="true"
 ValidationGroup="validationSSN" class="btn"
 type="submit">Search</button> </asp:Panel>  </div>
```

I also tried setting both `pnlSSN.DefaultButton = btnSSN.ClientID;` and     `pnlSSN.DefaultButton = btnSSN.ID;` but I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

`DefaultButton` must be ASP.Net button server control instead of html `Button`

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlSSN" DefaultButton="btnSSN">
    ...
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSSN" OnClick="btnSSN_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Besides, your asp:TextBox tag is not well-formatted. Remove `>` at the end of `Number">`

Comment: is there a way I can use button type instad of asp.net button? Some css rules are not working for asp button thats why I switched to button type. Thanks

Comment: No, you cannot. You need to fit CSS - not the other way around.